# Downloading flac with transmission

Tags: transmission, flac

I am new to using transmission to d/l FLAC pkgs from Archive.org. I notice the files are huge, and include ogg vorbit and two versions of MP3. Is it possible to configure so I only get FLAC and relavent FLAC files?

Comment: Depends on your download. If you are downloading a folder, user123492's answer will work for you. If you are downloading an archive, you will have to download the whole file. Even though, I bet the FLAC files are the biggest, for they are lossless and mp3 and ogg are compressed files.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the torrent file with Transmission, then a popup window appears asking you where to download the file (destination folder/path) and on that same window the files to be downloaded appear with a check box on their side (normally all boxes are checked), so what you'd like to do is to uncheck what you don't want to download (do that on that same window). Then hit OK and downloading will start.